# In Excel Pivot chart, I wanted to show the only the max amount transferred to customers in a single day (sum of all the transaction in a day)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-chart

Here is the sample excel input data & output in a chart I should be able to see the sum of transaction happened on 5th as that's the maximum amount.

Any help or lead will be highly appreciable.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting `Date` in the *Rows* area, `Sum of Amount Paid` in the *Values* area, then right-clicking on any of the dates in the Pivot Table, selecting `Filter`/`Top 10` and Show `Top` `1` Items by `Sum of Amount Paid`?

Comment: @JosWoolley Sir, that way it works. Never tried this option before.

Comment: @JosWoolley/@Mayukh Bhattacharya - Had one more doubt, can we un-group dates for only 1 Pivot table in a sheet or workbook, if the sheet or workbook is having multiple pivot tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about how you would do this using <kbd>PIVOT CHART</kbd> (Post edited, with help suggestion -- check below), but here is an example of using <kbd>EXCEL FORMULAS</kbd> to achieve using dynamic array formulas available in `MS365`.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, UNIQUE(D2:D7),
     b, MMULT(N(a=TOROW(D2:D7)),C2:C7),
     c, FILTER(HSTACK(a,b),MAX(b)=b),
     VSTACK({"Date","Amount Paid"},c))
```

---

Well, I tried to follow as suggested by **[Jos Woolley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17007704/jos-woolley)** Sir, and it gives the exact output as shown using the formula above.

Here are the steps:

- First place the Dates in Rows area and Amount Paid in Values as summarized as sum.

[image]

---

- Next click on Date Field --> Value Filters --> Top 10 and change the number 10 to 1.

[image]

---

- To get desired output.

[image]

---

For more efficient performance using Excel Formulas use <kbd>SUMIFS()</kbd> instead of <kbd>MMULT()</kbd> as suggested by **Jos Sir** in comments below.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, UNIQUE(D2:D7),
     b, SUMIFS(C2:C7,D2:D7,a),
     c, FILTER(HSTACK(a,b),MAX(b)=b),
     VSTACK({"Date","Amount Paid"},c))
```

---

Comment: Nice formula alternative! Though be aware that `MMULT` is more resource heavy than `SUMIFS`, so the definition for *b* could be replaced with the simpler and more efficient `SUMIFS(C2:C7,D2:D7,a)`.

Comment: @JosWoolley Sir, I agree, I will post that as well. But sir, as far i know, that `MMULT()` works with large data and is faster always? so is it wrong, can you correct me, i thought it was fast. Updated now sir. Thanks again!

Comment: `MMULT` is more flexible than `SUMIFS`, though not as fast.

Comment: @JosWoolley Sir, alright understood now!

Comment: Thanks @MayukhBhattacharya for this lengthy explanation :)